# Как отловить событие открытия файла в IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, плагин, события, jetbrains

Пишу простой плагин для IntelliJ IDEA. Так вот. Нужно чтобы при открытии файла в проекте выполнялся мой хендлер. Как это сделать? уже два часа разбираюсь с документацией от jetBrains, но пока туговато

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно отловить событие в `MessageBus` проекта:

```
MessageBus messageBus = project.getMessageBus();
messageBus.connect().subscribe(FileEditorManagerListener.FILE_EDITOR_MANAGER, new FileEditorManagerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void fileOpened(@NotNull FileEditorManager source, @NotNull VirtualFile file) {
        super.fileOpened(source, file);
    }

    @Override
    public void fileClosed(@NotNull FileEditorManager source, @NotNull VirtualFile file) {
        super.fileClosed(source, file);
    }

    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(@NotNull FileEditorManagerEvent event) {
        super.selectionChanged(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: Komdosh, пожалуйста, можно чуточку подробнее? В каком классе? Я так понимаю, в любом месте, главное, чтобы отработал данный код? И еще такой вопрос. В основном данный плагин делаю для файлов, открываемых по FTP и SFTP через Tools->Deployment->Browse remote host

Comment: вам нужно словить сначала project, например из event или менеджера, затем ещё нужно убедиться, что в том месте, где он вызывается, проект действительно существует и далее очевидно нужно отфильтровать как-то, как именно найти FTP файл не могу подсказать, не пользовался им из идеи